# Filling an Object with multiple variables in Java?

Tags: java, object

Is it possible to add multiple attributes to an Object attribute in a class? For example, I have a queue for a bar where you can order drinks by providing: drink name, drink quantity and table number. Do I have to create a variable for each or can I store multiple attributes in a single Object foo? Ty!

Comment: Grab your Java guide and read it again (or for the first time), if you don;t remember what objects are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to **define** a `class` (i.e. `class DrinkOrder`) and enumerate the *fields* of that class -- i.e. a `String drinkName`, `int quantity`, `String tableIdentifier`, etc.). Then when you **instantiate** that class into an instance, each instance can hold as many values as you have defined fields.

```
// Should protect the fields with accessors, implement Comparable, etc.
public class DrinkOrder {
    public String drinkName;
    public int quantity;
}

// Somewhere else
DrinkOrder alex = new DrinkOrder();
alex.drinkName = "Beer";
alex.quantity = 1;

DrinkOrder andy = new DrinkOrder();
andy.drinkName = "Amaro Averna";
andy.quantity = 1;

System.out.println("Andy wants " + andy.quantity + " " + andy.drinkName); // => Andy wants 1 Amaro Averna
```

You should take advantage of Java training (plentiful on the web) such as the original [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) or Josh Bloch's "Effective Java" or Kathy Sierra's "Head First Java"

Comment: -and you could have--for example-- a Bar class meant for handling the order. If design pattern concerns come into play, it makes sense to use the "command" pattern too, but that's probably beyond the scope of this question.